# Detect full IE version in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, browser-detection

First of all, I am sorry if it was already asked, but I would like to know how I can detect (using JavaScript) which **exact** version of IE is running.

I already know `window.navigator.userAgent` and `appVersion` which returns `... MSIE 8.0 ...`, but what I want is `8.0.6` or `8.0.9` (they have differences, some things that work in `8.0.9` do not work in `8.0.6`).

Comment: A question you should ask yourself is **why** do you want to do this? It's almost always better to use feature detection instead of browser and/or version detection. https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/

Comment: I have never seen IE go further than one-decimal version numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can detect this level of granularity via javascript - browser versions are detected from the user agent, and in IE8 the user agent doesn't go down to those versions.

More info on IE8 user agent strings here: http://www.useragentstring.com/_uas_Internet%20Explorer_version_8.0.php

If there are some things that only work in certain subversions I think you may have to do some sort of feature detection test rather than trying to ascertain the actual dot-dot-version...

Answer (score 0):

What about navigator.appVersion ?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_appversion.asp

However, you still may need to grab the value using regular expressions.

Comment: There is no difference between userAgent and appVersion when it comes to version numbering.